# Background with pattern overlay CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve background with pattern overlay, pattern with left side opacity.

This is my code.

```
background: #d20254 url(pattern-gray.png);
background-blend-mode: multiply;
background-position: right;
```

Result is this....

[image]

But it's not how i want. How i want you can see in this image.
[image]

Can anyone help me wit this how can i get this background?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have image with that kind of blur made (about 2000px width and height for single arrow), then put background from right side.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert an css color pattern definition in your `background` property before your image  url to create an overlay gradient color for your image:

```
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(210,2,84,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 53%), url(pattern-gray.png);
```

There a lot of online tool for generating css background gradient. Im using [this tool](https://cssgradient.io/) for example